# How to get the back button to actually take you back to the previous screen in xcode?

Tags: xcode, button, back

I am developing an app with xcode4.5 for iOS 6 and I mainly used the storyboard
I have multiple screens which on all of them I have a tool bar where I add a button with a back arrow on it so I want this button to take me to the previous screen when I tap on it I can not seem to set this with the storyboard so my question is how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a navigation controller which does the pushing/popping of the view controls

you will get the navigation bar for free.

Comment: No that's not what I need I must have the back button in the tool wich also have two other button that takes you to sub menus but I want this back button to work as a back button

Comment: yes it is ;) if you dont need the navbar, you dont have to use it but the controller is what makes the back functionality, then YOUR custom button would do: [self.navigationController popViewController]

Comment: Sorry but I still don't get it am I suppose to add a code or link something in the storyboard?

Comment: no you need to add a navigationController. you likely need code for the custom UI but I am not sure -- I dont use storyboards too much

Comment: Where do I write the code for self.navigationcontroller popviewcontroller?